# Android: cannot request a URL that ends with Backslash

Tags: java, android, string, syntax, backslash

I am writing a little App that controls the I/O of a network camera with the camera's HTTP API.
Basically you turn a port on with an url like "hostname.com/io/virtualinput.cgi?action=6:/"
and turn it off with "hostname.com/io/virtualinput.cgi?action=6:\"

When I call these URLS in Browser they work flawless. However when i do it in the App, I can only turn it on. I have replaced the Backslash in the String with \ but it still doesn't work. Is this the right way to do it?

```
    return new HttpGet("http://hostname.com/io/virtualinput.cgi?action=6:\\");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `\` with the URL-encoded value `%5c`.

Example:

```
return new HttpGet("http://hostname.com/io/virtualinput.cgi?action=6:%5c");
```

Comment: Such an easy fix! I don't know why I couldn't find this myself, but it works now. Thank you very much and have a nice day!